# Flask: 'session' vs. 'g'?

Tags: python, session, flask

I'm trying to understand the differences in functionality and purpose between `g` and `session`. Both are objects to 'hang' session data on, am I right? If so, what exactly are the differences and which one should I use in what cases?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

No, `g` is *not* an object to hang session data on. `g` data is not persisted between requests.

`session` gives you a place to store data *per specific browser*. As a user of your Flask app, using a specific browser, returns for more requests, the session data is carried over across those requests.

`g` on the other hand is data shared between different parts of your code base *within **one** request cycle*. `g` can be set up during `before_request` hooks, is still available during the `teardown_request` phase and once the request is done and sent out to the client, `g` is cleared.

Comment: So `session` is 'per client' data (based on a cookie?) and `g` is per-request data?

Comment: @AvivCohn: exactly. The advantage of `g` is that it exists across all of your request, is thread safe, and specific to your current app (if you were to *nest* Flask apps where one calls another this becomes important). So you can set a user object or database connection with a `before_request` hook, then access that same user or connection in your templates, and still have available in a teardown hook without having to pass it along to each call.